# Compare variables that correspond to a result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm fascinated by [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLnb2.jpg) and am curious how I would write the logic in Javascript.

For example, I choose `porcelain` for skin type, `ash blonde` for hair and `grey` for eyes. The Light Summer color palette (light green) would bode well for me because there's a match of light green across each type.

So far, I have stored all the color palettes in an array and assigned each skin/hair/eye variables with an object with its corresponding color dots. Is there a better way to approach this then what I've got?

Thanks! You'll be the first to try out my app when it's done :)

Comment: This is too broad... what do you want your app to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you store color palettes as arrays and then skin/hair/eye colors as objects with keys as the different options, you can easily use the intersection of these arrays to find the best palette. For example, the following outputs `'light summer'`.

```
function commonPalette(skinTone, hairColor, eyeColor) {
    return skinTone.filter(function (color) {
        if (hairColor.indexOf(color) !== -1 && eyeColor.indexOf(color) !== -1) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

var skinTone = {
        'porcelain': ['clear spring', 'clear winter', 'warm spring', 'light summer', 'light spring']  
    },
    hairColor = {
        'ash blonde': ['light summer', 'light spring']
    },
    eyeColor = {
        'grey': ['cool summer', 'light summer', 'soft summer']
    };

commonPalette(skinTone['porcelain'], hairColor['ash blonde'], eyeColor['grey']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dictionaries.

When you click the button **porcelain**, the the value of colors from the **skin** dictionary:

```
skin['porcelain']
```

And so on for all the other options.